# Inconsistent jquery fadeIn behaviour between frames/no frames on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, frameset

I've met inconsistent **jQuery** `fadeIn` method behavior if the main site is running inside a **frameset**. The effect is only on **IE** (tested on IE 9).

I have blocking UI element:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    background-color: #2b2922;
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity = 30);
}
```

This element is showed using `fadeIn` method. In details, it's the part of PrimeFaces code. After changing `fadeIn` to `fateTo`, everything works as supposed to:

```
this.blocker.fadeTo(0, 0.3);
```

Now, the blocker is transparent, so it's visible, but everything below is also visible through the 'glass'. Exactly why transparency is used for. And it works that way on anything but IE, when the whole application is running on enterprise portal, which is running it inside a **frameset**. The blocking 'glass' is completely not transparent, as if the opacity was ignored.

Inspecting nearer, I've found out that the inplace style for `filter:alpha` is added, making element not transparent, and it is made by `fadeIn` method. For some reason it is done only when running the application inside a frameset...

So my question is, why jQuery behaves this way specially when using a frameset? I'm using jQuery version **1.8.1**.

Comment: Are you seriously using frames and framesets (not just iFrame's)?

Comment: I don't think I could say we use them seriously since we've been developing the application without knowing it will be placed into frameset...